# Installed 20.04 over corrupt 18.04: goes to grub on boot

Tags: grub2, nvidia, 20.04

I had 18.04 installed on a new Ryzen 5 machine meant to run Folding@Home on two nVidia RTX 2060 cards. It worked fine for months, then after a live update would boot to a black screen with an X cursor.

I downloaded 20.04 to my Windows 10 machine and used Rufus to created an installation USB stick. Installation seemed to go well. I told the installer to erase the NVMe SSD. On trying to boot the new installation it usually goes to GRUB, but sometimes prompts for a login on an X-style high-resolution screen with my user name but won’t let me log in: no error if I give the right password, just a return to a prompt. Any ideas?

Edit: the installation software seems to be creating a new partition on the SSD on every installation attempt, even when I ask for the drive to be erased entirely...

Comment: You have to use Something Else install option and choose the existing / (root) partition as / for new install. It finds ESP and now uses swap file, so only / is required. You can add separate /home if desired & if it exists, you choose it during install, but DO NOT check the format box. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Thanks for replying. The SSD already has a small fat32 file system (few hundred Mb) and a big ext4 and I tried making the ext4 the /. (I have forgotten everything I ever knew of Unix or Linux.) Same result of installation. Boot-Repair doesn’t seem happy with the BIOS (?) and I can’t see how to remedy that.

Comment: With my luck I could put in a brand new SSD and I’d get exactly the same result...